# Visual Studio C++ Code Formatting - return type + classname::func indentation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-formatting

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for developing C++ code. I am used to format my code as follows:

```
void
SomeThing::DoesSomething()
{
    // brilliant code 
}
```

However, when using VS2012 code formatter, it always turns my code into this:

```
void 
    SomeThing::DoesSomething()
{
    // still brilliant
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this indentation of the ClassName::Func() in the line below the return type without completely turning off auto indentation?

Comment: You are not going to get this from VS2012.  If this is your preferred style then you'll need to stay away from the Format Document command.  There are a bunch of new options added to VS2013 to control formatting, you'd have to take a look.

Comment: Same problem in VS2013 Preview.

Answer (score 3):

This is as close as you can get to your desired settings:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Tabs -> Indenting -> Block
```

It doesn't turn off indentation (when you are coding at 1 tab and press enter, it will still be at 1 tab), but it stops it from indenting things for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but the problem mainly occurs when using whole document formatting. And this doesn't fix that, so +1 but not accept.